# CHtml::listData() issue

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I want to list checkboxes which the array retrieves me them..

my controller action codes are:

```
public function actionSech ($radio)
{
    $sql = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
                ->select ('m.maraq')
                ->from ('maraq m')
                ->where ('m.idsinif=:ids', [':ids'=>$radio])
                ->queryAll();
    $this->renderPartial('sech', array('sql'=>$sql));
}
```

**sech.php**

```
<style>
    .multiselect-group{display: none !important;}
</style>
<?php
    print_r($sql);
    $cat = CHtml::listData($sql, 'idmaraq', 'maraq');
    print_r($cat);
?>
```

the `print_r($sql);` result is:

```
> Array ( [0] => Array ( [maraq] => Şəxsi sağlamlıq sistemləri ) [1] =>
> Array ( [maraq] => Xəstələrin təhlükəsizliyi üçün İKT ) [2] => Array (
> [maraq] => Virtual fizioloji insan ) [3] => Array ( [maraq] =>
> "Virtual fizioloji insan" sahəsində beynəlxalq əməkdaşlıq ) )
```

but the `print_r($cat);` result is:

```
> Array ( [] => "Virtual fizioloji insan" sahəsində beynəlxalq
> əməkdaşlıq )
```

So, I couldn't understand; what is the problem that `$cat` is not returns the same query with the `$sql`?

Please explain. Thanks.

Best,
Mirjalal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem.

Edited codes:

**action**

```
public function actionSech ($radio)
{
    $maraq = new Maraq();
    $sql = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
        ->select('maraq')
        ->from('maraq m')
        ->where('m.idsinif=:ids', [':ids' => $radio])
        ->queryAll();

    $this->renderPartial('sech', array('sql' => $sql, 'maraq'=>$maraq));
}
```

**view file**

```
<?php
    print_r($sql);
    $cat = CHtml::listData($maraq->findAll(), 'idsinif', 'maraq');
echo "<br>";
echo "<br>";
echo "<br>";
    print_r($cat);
?>
```

Results are the same :))

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The associative array returned by `CDbCommand::queryAll` contains only the field `maraq` and does not contain the field `idmaraq`, specified as the 2nd parameter of the function `CHtml::listData`. Thus try to change the line

```
 ->select ('m.maraq')
```

to

```
->select ('m.idmaraq, m.maraq')
```

or

```
->select ('*')
```

Comment: 2 questions: 1) what is the structure of your `maraq` table? 2) could you check if the field `idmaraq` is not null for all your records?

Comment: 1) in `maraq` table I have 3 columns: `idsinif` is `int`, `idmaraq` is `int`, `maraq` is `varchar(250)`
2) records of the `idmaraq` starts form 1 and there is no any null record(s).

Comment: To achieve the desired result your `$sql` array should contain the `idmaraq` key, i.e. the result of `print_r($sql)` must look approximately like this `Array ( [0] => Array ( [idmaraq] => 1 [maraq] => Şəxsi sağlamlıq sistemləri ) [1] => Array ( [idmaraq]=> 2 [maraq] => Xəstələrin təhlükəsizliyi üçün İKT ) ...`